# Debounce on stream function continuously

Tags: javascript, lodash

How do I make debounce continuously run while the function is still subscribe to api? The api stream sometimes send burst data and I wanted to avoid getting all at once.

```
const trade = async () => {
  let liqStream = api.futuresLiquidationStream(pair, async (data) => {
    const currentTimeUTC = moment().utc();
    console.log(currentTimeUTC.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"))
  });
}
const init = async () => {
  debounce(trade, 5000)();
}

init();
```